# How can i print the backward in staircase problem?

Tags: java

Here the problem"Write a program that prints a staircase of size n."

```
 for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
         {
            for(int j = 1; j < n; j++)
             {
                if((i + j) > n) 
                {
                    System.out.print("#");
                } 
                else
                {
                     System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();


     #
    ##
   ###?
  ####
 #####
######
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn what kinds of questions are on topic for this site.  If you can [edit] your question to make it on topic, please do so.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Please provide a link and more information to the problem you are trying to solve. What the expected result should be, and what you want to use to achieve it.

Comment: @Type-Style We don't usually ask for links here - links (other than ones to official documentation etc.) are considered something that will disappear. This includes links to code challenge sites etc. All the information needed to understand the problem has to be included in the question itself.

Comment: @RealSkeptic now that the question is edited again I understand.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is pretty working with couple of changes, initialize i and j to `1` and change condition to `<=`

```
int n =5;
     for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
     {
        for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
         {
            if((i + j) > n) 
            {
                System.out.print("#");
            } 
            else
            {
                 System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
     }
```

**Output**

```
    #
   ##
  ###
 ####
#####
```